# child pid ... exit signal Segmentation fault (11)

Tags: segmentation-fault

This appears in Debian Lenny / Apache 2 logfiles:

```
[notice] child pid ... exit signal Segmentation fault (11)
```

Sometimes it appears once a month, sometimes once a week. Since yesterday this error appears in logfiles 2-3 times per hour. No other errors.

I have only 1 website running, no other people on the server. I didn't change anything on the server - didn't update anything, didn't change any scripts, didn't upload new scripts, nothing. There are no scripts which are being used only sometimes so, if segmentation fault is being caused by some php script, such errors should appear all the time, not only sometimes.

Server load under 1.

Any ideas what can cause this error and why it appears only sometimes and why the number of this error increases?

What are the consequences of this error? What happends on the server when it occurs? May I just ignore it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

mostly , this problem comes due to the dynamic modules in-comoatiblity or corruption. the modules fail to work properly and apaches crashes with this result.
one workaround is that find all the dynamic loaded modules by this command:

> httpd -l

Try to turn on DEBUG mode of log for apache, which is set to WARN by default.
and the best is if you can get the CoreDump of apache. if you do not know how to get it, i can tell you.

if you cannot, then look at all the php extensions in php extensions folder.
try to disable the modules and extensions one by one then you will know that which module is creating this issue.